# HtmlUnit: click() function doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm having trouble with the click() function from HtmlUnit.
It doesn't do anything for me.

```
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("xxx");
page = (HtmlPage) page.getFrameByName("xxx").getEnclosedPage();
HtmlElement test = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='s81']");
page = test.click();
```

```
<div id="s81" class="mmenu" data-bind="click: function(){ CheckId('Counternav',mes()[120]) }, text: mes()[120]">Counter</div>
```

The div is found, that isn't the problem. The click() function just doesn't change anything to the page. Am I unsing the function wrong?

I hope somebody can help and many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please try to change the variable name html to any other. May be due to reserved word it triggers the problem. I am not sure this works or not but you may try this.

Comment: Please add whole working example of your code. Are you writing this code in Javascript? If yes, please add your html and css code as well if any.You can also add your code to jsfiddle and provide the link so that someone can take a look and resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the java-script click event on that element as :

```
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("xxx");
page = (HtmlPage) page.getFrameByName("xxx").getEnclosedPage();
HtmlElement test = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='s81']");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", test);
```